# PollEvent not working without mouse movement[SDL]

Tags: c++, sdl, mouse

PollEvent is bypassed if mouse isn't moving within window or any key is not pressed when supposed to run animation. Here's the code:

```
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG | IMG_INIT_JPG;
    if (IMG_Init(imgFlags) != imgFlags)
    {
        std::cout << IMG_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("NRG", 200, 200, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED| SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);


    isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
        {
            heroImg = LoadTxt("image.png", renderer);
            SDL_QueryTexture(heroImg, NULL, NULL, &textureWidth, &textureHeight);
            frameWidth = textureWidth / 3;
            frameHeight = textureHeight / 4;
            heroRct.x = 0;
            heroRct.y = 0;
            heroRct.h = frameHeight;
            heroRct.w = frameWidth;
            frameTime++;
            if (60 / frameTime == 4)
            {
                frameTime = 0;
                heroRct.x += frameWidth;
                if (heroRct.x >= textureWidth)
                    heroRct.x = 0;
            }
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, heroImg, &heroRct, NULL);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    windowSurface = NULL;
    renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();
```

Other stuff like SDL_Event ev; is included in .h file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody with the same problem:
Put your render etc. outside of the **while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev))** loop :)

Stupid mistake, pretty hard to solve for begginer :)